# Confused with category scope in Magento 2

Tags: category, magento2.2.8

I have a Magento store with 3 stores scope (Brazil, USA and Global) and just one root category, but now I have a main category called 'Off Price'. In this category I need to put specific products for Brazil, USA and Global, but, for example, when i remove a product from Brazil a need to let this product in USA and Global, but the products is been removed in all web sites.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would create 3 categories, one for each store view. You can disable the unneeded categories on other store views and set the url key on the enabled store view so each one can share the same url key at the correct store scope.